# PhpSpreadsheet - how to determine if a number is formatted as text?

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I have a simple spreadsheet with a number formatted as text:

[image: LibreOffice screenshot]

I want to use PhpSpreadsheet to determine that the number is indeed formatted as text instead of the default "General". So I do this:

```php
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);

$cell = $reader->load('index.xlsx')->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1');
var_dump($cell->getValue(), $cell->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode());
```

But the result is always this:

> float(12345)
>   string(7) "General"

How to determine if the number is formatted as "Text"?

Comment: As a test, open the file with Excel again, change the value from `12345` to `12346`, save the file, and test again. When I do that, I get the correct result.

Comment: @SeanBright that didn't help, still "General". I'm using LibreOffice instead of MS Office, so that might be a factor. I'd see if I can get a trial version of MS Office to try it with, but that's ultimately not useful as this question is based on a user's problem and I can't make MS's software a requirement.

Comment: Agreed, I am just telling you what worked for me. There is [a now closed issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1124) in the `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` repository that took me down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write it in your reader code '$reader->setReadDataOnly(True);', that mean read out pure data with out formmating, in your reader code. See [documentation](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/IReader.html#method_setReadDataOnly).

See line 5 on your code.

You should use

```
$reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE);
```

Than you should be able to readout the formating information from the excel file.

```
 $format = $sheet->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

Comment: That's what I'm using, but `getFormatCode` returns "General" instead, that's the whole point.

Comment: you should try to set `$reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE);` to the numberformating with '@' You say to the reader read out only the puredate without the formating. Then the reader return only general as cellformat

Comment: There's no point in me setting it. I have to know where users set it using Excel or LibreOffice.

Comment: You write it in your reader code '$reader->setReadDataOnly(True);' in your reader code. you will not see any user formatting if you tell phpspreadsheet that it should only use data. See line 5 on your code.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I'll try that later (I'm at work right now and I have the test files at home) and post the results. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, that worked. Can you edit your answer to say that `$reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);` is actually the solution? Because currently the solution is in the comments, not the answer itself. I will award the bounty tomorrow, SO doesn't let me do it yet.